# Simulating location by updating GPX file from entering coordinates in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build some logic in swift to update the gpx file so that I can simulate the location on the iOS device after entering coordinates in the format of "33.333333,-122.222222" but in my code the program is crashing as soon as I have entered the coordinates and the coordinatesTextView variable is apparently nil.

I am pretty sure that the textview and button label are properly connected in the story board with the ViewController file. I have double checked several times.

Here Is the ViewController.swift code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    var gpxData: String = ""
    
    @IBOutlet weak var coordinatesTextView: UITextView!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        // Check if the coordinatesTextView outlet is connected
        guard coordinatesTextView != nil
            else
                {
                    print("Error: coordinatesTextView outlet is not connected")
                        return
                }
        
        
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                
        // Load the initial GPX file
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Location", ofType: "gpx")
            else {
                return
            }
        gpxData = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
        
        // Start receiving location updates
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func updateLocation(latitude: Double?, longitude: Double?) {
        if let latitude = latitude, let longitude = longitude {
                currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                coordinatesTextView.text = "\(latitude), \(longitude)"
            } else {
                print("Error: latitude or longitude is nil")
            }
    }
    
    func updateGPXFile(latitude: String, longitude: String) {
        // Replace the latitude and longitude values in the GPX file
        let newGPXData = gpxData.replacingOccurrences(of: "LATITUDE", with: latitude)
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "LONGITUDE", with: longitude)
        
        // Write the new GPX data to the file
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Location", ofType: "gpx") else { return }
        try! newGPXData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        
        // Reload the GPX data
        gpxData = newGPXData
    }
    
    @IBAction func updateCoordinates(_ sender: Any) {
        
        print("updateCoordinates tapped")
        
        guard let text = coordinatesTextView.text
            else {
                print("Error: coordinatesTextView text is nil")
                    return
            }
        let coordinates = text.split(separator: ",")
        guard coordinates.count == 2
            else {
                print("Error: invalid coordinates")
                    return
            }
        let newLatitude = coordinates[0].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let newLongitude = coordinates[1].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        guard let latitude = Double(newLatitude), let longitude = Double(newLongitude)
            else {
                print("Error: invalid coordinates")
                    return
            }
        
        guard latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90, longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180
            else {
                print("Error: invalid coordinates")
                    return
            }
        
        // Update the coordinates text view
        coordinatesTextView.text = "\(newLatitude), \(newLongitude)"
        
        print(coordinatesTextView.text) // should print the new coordinates
        
        // Update the GPX file with the new coordinates
        updateGPXFile(latitude: newLatitude, longitude: newLongitude)
        
        // Update the location
        updateLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }

    
}


extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLocation = locations.last
        
    }
    
    // hide keyboard
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

I have formatted the Location.gpx file like in the same folder as ViewController.swift:

```
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
    
    
    <gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
        <wpt lat="LATITUDE" lon="LONGITUDE">
            <ele>0.000000</ele>
        </wpt>

    
</gpx>
```

If there is anyone out there with knowledge about this, could I get some insight on how I can fix my code?

The error that I get is: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" inside the updateCoordinates function. The line that it errors on is:

```
guard let text = coordinatesTextView.text
            else {
                print("Error: coordinatesTextView text is nil")
                    return
            }
```

I am trying to update the gpx file that is located in the same folder as the ViewController file programmatically by entering the latitude and longitude coordinates in the format of "xx.xxxxxx,-xx.xxxxxx" in a textview label and having simulate the location on each button press.

Is this something that can be done? From what I've seen on other google searches, I get the impression it is, but I could be wrong.

Much like how you can manually update coordinates in the gpx file to simulate location, is there a way to do this programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: You can't write to the bundle. It is read only.

Comment: By writing to the bundle I assume you mean writing to the gpx file from the textview's, that this is not something that can be done?

Comment: `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Location", ofType: "gpx") ` returns a file path in your application bundle. This is a read only file. You can't write back to the bundle. So no, this is. It something that can be done.